# Use CSS translate transform with jquery draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I create an example using an annotation with SVG image.

I place an annotation over SVG in some position. For pan and zoom, I use [svg pan zoom](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) library

To init SVG pan zoom, I used:

```
svgPanZoom("#panzoom svg", {
        panEnabled: true,
         controlIconsEnabled: false,
         zoomEnabled: true,
         dblClickZoomEnabled: true,
         mouseWheelZoomEnabled: true,
         zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.2,
         minZoom: 0.2,
         maxZoom: 20,
         fit: true,
         contain: true,
         center: true,
         refreshRate: 'auto',
         onPan: function(ev) {
             console.log(ev);
           $(".annotation").css("transform", "translate(" + ev.x + "px," + ev.y + "px)");
        }
    });
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="panzoom" style="text-align: center">
        <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="basic" id="svg2" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="900px" height="900px"
     viewBox="0 0 900 900" xml:space="preserve">
...

</svg>
</div>
```

For dragging annotation, I use jQuery UI draggable:

```
$(".annotation").draggable({cursor: "move"});
```

See the complete fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y5nzqudz/

The problem is that when I pan SVG and after that I want to move annotation then somehow the cursor and yellow block are moved unexpected...

I see that jQuery UI draggable uses top and left position and svg pan zoom uses translate css.

Can you advice me how to fix it ?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure this is what you are looking for but: https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/

Comment: No over SVG ... I want to use over annotation which is simply a div element... I want to apply same transform using jquery UI draggable